# MacBook Air is stuck at "Downloading Additional Components"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I recently reset my MacBook Air to its factory settings. I am now reinstalling os x yosemite but the installing process is taking forever... is it the wifi that's having problems? Or is it just my laptop? Is there a way to fix this, make it faster?

Comment: Press Command-L to bring up the installation log, and then change the dropdown menu from "Show Errors Only" to "Show All Logs." If nothing new ever comes up in the log after quite some time (and keep in mind that their time stamps are all in Pacific Time), then you've got cause for alarm. If new stuff shows up on a regular basis, then the installer is working and the only problem is that you're not a very patient person. :)

Comment: Thanks @user2460, you should really make this the answer. I have a lot of experience doing troubleshooting with Macs and I never knew this existed, and your advice helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was downloading OS X Mountain Lion and was faced with the same issue. I had to look for a faster internet connection and it worked. Try that.